# set Nonnumeric as they come in to null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

I have a paymentHistory field that is an int that tracks how many payments have been made from the account before. I have a source that is varchar for this field and someone enters 1.11 by accident on the front end. I can't change my source but I want to be able to allow only numeric and convert the non-numeric to null values. Can someone please give an example how I would convert values in this PaymentHistory column to only numeric or null. Thanks!

Comment: Please show some sample data and the update query used.

Comment: But `1.11` is a numerical value...

Comment: @larnu I mean an int. I want it to only be compatible with an int because my target is an int and it failed to insert into my target

Comment: So 1.11 should become null not 1?

Comment: I would like to do null if possible, but I will take any examples and try them out to see which one works best with the business

Comment: Why not add `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the table?

Comment: @Larnu I would rather set it to null if possible

Comment: But assuming that `'1.11'` should be `'1'` or `NULL` could be an even worse assumption. Stop people inserting bad data in the first place.

Comment: Well test the value using `%` and if there is a remainder set it null using a case expression.

Comment: Considering that a `varchar` that represents a `decimal` can't be converted to an `int`, `TRY_CONVERT` would also be an option. But still, stopping the bad data at the `INSERT` and refusing it is a much better plan.

Answer (score 3):

You can *reject* non-numeric values with a `check` constraint:

```
alter table chk_paymenthistory add constraint chk_paymenthistory_num
    check (num not like '%[^0-9]%');
```

This only allows digits into the column.  But you don't want to *reject* the value, you want to replace it with `NULL`.

If you are inserting the rows using `insert`, you can use `try_cast()`/`try_convert()`:

```
insert into paymenthistory ( . . . )
    values ( . . ., try_cast(num as int), . . .);
```

This will convert the value to an integer (and you could use `bigint` or `numeric` instead).  It will then be saved as a string -- but will be `null` if it is not a valid number.

That leaves you with a trigger for other situations.  But what other situation?  What comes to mind is `bulk insert`, but that doesn't invoke triggers by default. You *can* turn them on, if you want this functionality.